# Issue with generating a mock for an interface

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm currently trying to build mocks for an interface (defined here as the Policy class) which only has one method, `check`; as seen below I'm basically just replacing it with a stub method which always returns a known value:

```
$mockBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder(Policy::class);
$allowMock = $mockBuilder->getMock();
$allowMock->method('check')->willReturn(Vote::ALLOW);
```

It registers as an object implementing `Policy`, as it should, but whenever the `check` method is called it only ever returns `null`. What am I doing wrong in my construction here?

Comment: have you tried with the full namespace instead of the `::class`?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, `::class` returns the full namespaced version of the class and the returned mock reads as implementing the interface as expected; none of my type hints in actual code cause problems with it at least.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that solves your problem, but to mock interfaces, you should use `getMockForAbstractClass()`:

```
$allowMock = $mockBuilder->getMockForAbstractClass();
```